# For Each method in VBA not working

Tags: vba

I am currently struggling to get the For Each method working in my VBA in Excel 2010.

I have used the methoed before and had no problem but for the life of me I cannot seem to get the new function I have written to work.

Here it is:

```
Sub A2_Color_Bob()

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Sheets
Range("A2").Value = "Bob"
Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Not a VBA expert, but do you not need to actually use sh, i.e sh.Range("A2").Value = "Bob"

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it's not working is that you haven't specified which sheet in this line

`Range("A2").Value = "Bob"`

Therefore, the default sheet will be used, i.e. the `ActiveSheet`

Hence, as others have also mentioned, it should be changed to

`sh.Range("A2").Value = "Bob"`

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that's your Range is global, but you're trying to set a specific cell's value.

Did some checking and this works.

Sub A2_Color_Bob()

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Sheets
sh.Cells(1, 1).Value = "bob"
Next sh

End Sub

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Range is global"... The correct explanation is in @sam092's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19722086/119775).

Answer (score 0):

change for each sh in sheets , to ...in worksheets

or can also do
    dim i as long

```
for i=1 to worksheets.count
  sheets(i).range("A2")=bob"
next i
```